# Testing of an algorithm on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am new to this site but not new to SE. I am examining an algorithm that has been published and the software that comes along with the algorithm. Are questions related to testing of the algorithm using some sample data on topic ? I presume that they would be based on the tags that are available but being new I just want to check before I post something irrelevant. The data structure is a Skip List but I could not find any tags related to that data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends.

Are your questions about how the algorithm (in pseudocode) can be tested *in principle*? Such as, which strategies would be appropriate, how to generate random test instances, etc.
Then yes, probably ontopic.

Are they about how to use some testing framework to test *an implementation*? Such as, how to implement a certain test strategy, or how to generate random numbers in language X, etc.
No, probably offtopic. [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and/or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) are more suited.

Comment: it is the former according to me but I maybe wrong. Anyways once the question is posted I will be informed one way or the other. Thanks for the clarification.